# invalid ID field: 00128000003MKtxAAG order by LastModifiedDate DESC

Tags: query

```
queryString = 'Select id,'+string.join(new List<string>(tempset), ',')+' from '+relatedObject+' Where '+referenceFieldApiNameFromPage+'=\''+(Id)sobjectIdFromPage+ ' order by LastModifiedDate DESC '+ '\'  limit 10000';
```

Show Record in order by LastModifiedDate DESC but its throw

> invalid ID field: 00128000003MKtxAAG order by LastModifiedDate DESC

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try below code. It seems you are missing `'` mark and at the end you have unwanted `'` mark.

```
queryString = 'Select id,'+string.join(new List<string>(tempset), ',')+' from '+relatedObject+' Where '+referenceFieldApiNameFromPage+'=\''+(Id)sobjectIdFromPage+ '\' order by LastModifiedDate DESC '+ '  limit 10000';
```